# MongoDB cannot search againse utf-8 characters like MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a document in `users` collection which has a name field with value of 'unité'. Now, if I search again this collection using the following command (I'm using mongoose as db driver):

```
User.findOne({name: new RegExp('unite'), 'i')});
```

But it returns nothing since `unite` doesn't match `unité` exactly. However, when using MySQL I can use the simple like command and it still returns result for me.

Is there any way to perform a search query in MongoDB which offers the same behavior like the `like` query in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo supports UTF-8 by default. It may be a driver issue.

Comment: Actually, when I use MongoDB client to query it still returns null.